# Undeclared variable error 1327

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1327

Undeclared variable: export

```
SELECT a.tokoh_id, a.tokoh_name, a.thumb, a.subtitle, c.total_polling 
FROM td_tokoh AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN td_user AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN td_polling AS c ON c.tokoh_id = a.tokoh_id 
ORDER BY c.total_polling DESC 
LIMIT export,10

Filename: /mainData/apps/poty/admin/models/polling/mpol.php

Line Number: 18
```

please help me

Comment: `export` is not a SQL keyword. I think you are using PHP, so try `$export` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use limit as

```
LIMIT 0,10
```

or

```
LIMIT $export,10
```

export word is nothig that is why you are getting error. Convert it into a variable as $export.

Answer (score 0):

limit can be use like:

```
LIMIT 10  //this will fetch first 10 records
```

or

```
LIMIT 0,10  // this will fetch 0 to 10 recores
```

And if you are using some PHP variable than do it like below:

```
LIMIT $export,10
```

You can see more info about limit here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: thanks for your attention but before i can export but right now i don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

```
set  @a = 1;
select cl1 from test order by cl1 desc limit @a,@a;
```

syntax error 
error code 1064

so maybe `limit` can't use variable